# Is [F(a, b, c) = a' + b] functionally or logically complete?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm having a problem determining whether [F(a, b, c) = a' + b] is  functionally(logically) complete or not.
I would really appreciate it if you could help me.
P.S: I can't have 1 or 0 as input.

Comment: you can derive 1 by F(a,a,a) and ~a by F(a,1,a). Then proceed to prove any of the universal gate equivalents.

Comment: @RinkeshP Unfortunately $F(a,1,a)=1$. You cannot implement a NOT gate using $F$ (and without the constant 0) since otherwise you'd be able to generate $0$, and ultimately implement a NAND gate. This can't be possible since $F$ (without the constant 0) is not universal.

Comment: @Steven Oops, yeah. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not allowed to have the constant $0$ as input then you cannot implement the constant function $0$ using only $F$.

To see this, let $C$ be a minimum (w.r.t. the number of gates) circuit that uses only $F$ gates and that computes $C(x) = 0$. We will show that this leads to a contradiction. Since $C$ must contain at least one gate (otherwise $C(1)=1$), we can
consider the last gate $F(a,b,c)$ of $C$. In order for such a gate to return $0$ we must have that $b=0$. But then there must be a smaller circuit that computes $0$.

If you are allowed to use $0$, then the gate $F$ is universal.
Indeed $1 = F(0,0,0)$ and we can simulate a NAND gate, which is universal:
$$a \text{ NAND } b = \overline{a \cdot b} = \overline{a} + \overline{b} = \overline{a} + (\overline{b} +0) = F(a, F(b,0,0),0).$$

Comment: in general if it was asked is $f(a,b,c) = a' + b$ functionally complete? then can I take inputs a, b or c to be 0, 1 without deriving $f(a,b,c) = 0 (or) 1$? to prove $f$ is functionally complete?